# Is there any information on cities where most of the citizens are undead?

Tags: dnd-4e, undead

In *Open Grave* it says:

> Other places, such as the city of Eredu, take a more proactive approach. In Eredu, undead that want to be citizens must submit to a process of authorization to gain unrestricted access to the metropolis.

However, I can't find any more information about this place. I want to create a city that is mostly civil and populated by undead. My PC's hate undead and I think it would be a fun twist to have them negotiate a place like this.

I'm looking for resources and suggestions.

Comment: I assume you're most interested in "canon" D&D, but what about pulling things from other settings? The Skullstone Archipelago in _Exalted_, for example, fits what you're looking for to a T. Just don't go digging too deep into the identity of the Silver Prince, nor get caught snooping around Isle Five... (The Silver Prince is actually the deathlord The Bodhissatva Annointed By Dark Water, and Isle Five is a secret manufactory for a dark navy.)

Comment: Are you interested in information just from Dnd settings or would other fantasy sources be ok ?

Comment: Primarily DnD, but other sources would be interesting too.

Answer (score 7):

#### Try looking at Eberron

Particularly the nation of Karrnath, where mindless undead are accepted implements of war, smarter undead have been created for yet-better warmaking, truly intelligent undead can be accepted members of society, and the Blood of Vol cult to undeath-as-immortality is a majority religion.

#### 3.5’s *Libris Mortis* has a little detail on undead societies

Unfortunately, not much, but on pages 14 and 15, there are descriptions of societies where undead are “Open Members” and also of purely or dominantly “Undead Societies.” Sigil is listed as one tolerant place where undead may be open members, while a city named Nocturnus is referenced as having a Pale Ward where undead are the only legal residents. Nocturnus is mentioned a few more times in *Libris Mortis*, but unfortunately never in any great detail that I can find.

#### *Fallout 3*’s Underworld might be somewhat useful

It’s a city of “ghouls” (but *Fallout* ghouls are actually alive, just made to look hideous by radiation); might be relevant to use as an idea of what it’s like, though I don’t recall the game really going into too much detail other than “oooh, we’re spooky and different, but peaceful; how do you feel about that?” Which might work for you, but you might want a bit more.

Comment: Fallout 3's ghouls aren't undead, though - just afflicted by radiation to look repulsive. They're outcasts in society and have made their own home. Might still be useful, but it should be said they're not actually undead.

Comment: Amusingly, Fallout: Equestria's ghouls *are* undead and immortal, in case you want to discuss their society and whatnot.

Comment: +1 for the Fallout reference. I just wanted to add to doppelgreener's comment... while the ghouls of Fallout are not technically 'undead' like your traditional zombie/vampire/skeletal warrior, Fallout Ghouls are practically immune to aging (they age extremely slowly). There are a few cases of nonferal ghouls that claim to have been alive since the bombs fell. Here's a link! http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Ghoul

Answer (score 7):

## Another alternative is Hammerfast[<sup>wotc</sup>](https://www.wizards.com/dnd/Product.aspx?x=dnd/products/dndacc/255190000)

[image: Hammerfast Cover]

From the first paragraph of the supplement:

> History walks the streets of Hammerfast in the form of the dead, the dwarves and orcs who died in this place more than a century ago. They are now ghosts consigned to wander Hammerfast's streets until the end of days. Hammerfast was once a necropolis, a collection of tombs where the dwarflords interred their people. As the dwarves' wealth grew, their burial chambers changed from simple stone sepulchers to lavish treasure vaults filled with the material wealth garnered over a lifetime.

... and further on ...

> **THREE UNIQUE TRAITS**
>
> There are three points that make Hammerfast unique.
>
> • Hammerfast is a town where the living dwell among the dead. The buildings are tombs and sepulchers, cleared of rubble and refurbished to serve as homes and businesses.
>
> • Some of the tombs remain sealed. Their treasures are a powerful lure for adventurers, but raiding such a tomb is punishable by death. In some of the inhabited tombs, secret doors to forgotten passages and chambers await discovery.
>
> • The dwarves must endure the presence of orcs. As part of the divine compact that created the town, Gruumsh demanded that his dead be honored, too, by a temple devoted to his power.